# How to blur whole layout when popup arrives in android

Tags: android

can anybody tell How to blur whole layout when popup arrives in android can anybody provide example
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may be helpful to you:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount=0.0f;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```